# node http-get detect connection lost

Tags: node.js, http, stream

I am using node http to download a remote file and save it on disc.
It appears that if while downloading the file the connection is lost no event of 'error' or 'close' is emmited.

I was using [request](https://github.com/request/request) before but I was getting the same behaviour, my code with http.get is like the following:

```
    const urlData = url.parse(baseUrl)
    const getOptions = {
        protocol:urlData.protocol,
        host:urlData.host,
        path:urlData.path
    }
    http.get(getOptions,(downloadResponse)=>{
         if(downloadResponse.statusCode===200){
            const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(SOME_FILE)
            downloadResponse.on("error", (err)=> {
                console.log('Download response error ')
            })
            writeStream.on("error",(err)=>{
                console.log('Write stream error ')
            })
            downloadResponse.on('close',()=>{
                console.log('Download response close')
            })
            writeStream.on('finish', () =>{
                console.log('Everything fine!')
            })
        }
        else{
            console.log('error '+downloadResponse.statusCode)
        }
    })
    .on('error',(err)=>{
        console.log('Error on request')
        console.log(err)
    })
```

If I enter on airplane mode or disconnect the download the proccess just never end . Am I missing some event or something like this?

Comment: Try catch `close event` for http.

Comment: Already tried, nothing is fired , will update the snippet with it .I am using a workaround of detecting it somewhere else and unpiping myself